# Setting instance variable value in model using controller with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, modal-dialog

The check in the controller evaluates properly for `if o.my_method('a')`, although when this happens `@var` stays nil in the model. Where am I going wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Controller:

```
def action
  o = Object.new
  if o.my_method('a')
    ...
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Object
  def my_method(args)
    ['a', 'b', 'c'].any? do |i|
      @var = true if args.include?(i)
    end
  end

  def my_method2
    if @var == true
      do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you adding methods to `Object`? That's usually very risky and ill-advised. Also do you mean "model"? "Modal" is a specific technical term

Comment: Yea, sorry I do mean Model. I'm not sure of another way to do this.. The model doesn't have to know about `my_method`, but if I do all this stuff in the controller, I need the model (`my_method2`) to know the outcome (true/false) of that check, whether its performed in the model or not.. Any suggestions? @tadman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up version of your code that's actually more Ruby-like in nature:

```
class MyModel
  attr_accessor :example

  VALID_VALUES = %w[ a b c ]

  def demo_method(value)
    @example = true if VALID_VALUES.include?(value)
  end
end

model = MyModel.new

model.demo_method('x')

model.example
# => nil

model.demo_method('a')

model.example
# => true
```

The problem you had in your original code is you're setting the value inside an `any?` block which also does a test for inclusion. This nesting isn't required.

You also don't need to test `x == true` since `x` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This almost works, `@example` is returning true in `demo_method`, although `@example` seems to be nil when calling it somewhere else in the model..

Comment: Any suggestions @tadman? For example: 
`def demo_method2
puts "abc" if @example
end`

Comment: It works fine inside the context of the `model`. Aka, in your example, `model.example`. But when actually trying to access the global variable `@example` elsewhere, it's nil. @tadman

Comment: `@example` is not a global variable, it's local to the context of the object instance. That's what `attr_accessor` is for, so you can get access to it. Normally it's considered bad form, even rude to access another objects private instance variables. You should use one of the public interfaces, such as here with `model.example`.

Comment: So if you need a condition based on that, then `if model.example` and so on.